# Inequality involving inradii and the segments from center of incircle and the vertexes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Show that, in every triangle, the following equality holds:
$$\frac {1} {AI^2}+\frac {1} {BI^2}+\frac {1} {CI^2}+\frac {1} {AI \cdot BI \cdot CI}=\frac {1} {r^2},$$ where $I$ is the center of the incircle and $r$ is the inradius.

Comment: Is this an inequality?

Comment: I edited the question, sorry! @Sawarnik

Comment: Are you sure its valid? I drew a quick GeoGebra diagram and it didn't come out to be 1. :/

Comment: Perhaps you mean $$\frac{1}{AI^2} + \frac{1}{BI^2}+\frac{1}{CI^2}-\frac{2r}{AI\cdot BI\cdot CI}=\frac{1}{r^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $BC=a,AC=b,AB=c$, $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ and $A$ the area of the triangle . It is well known that 
\begin{align*}
\vec{AI}=\frac{b\vec{AB}+c\vec{AC}}{a+b+c} \iff \frac{1}{AI^2}=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{(b\vec{AB}+c\vec{AC})^2}=\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2b^2c^2(\cos A +1)}
\end{align*}
Since $\cos A+1=2s(s-a)/bc$, we can rewrite the latter:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{AI^2}=\frac{s}{(s-a)bc}
\end{align*}
Similarly, $1/BI^2=s/(s-b)ca$ and $1/CI^2=s/(s-c)ab$. From here,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{AI^2\cdot BI^2\cdot CI^2}=\frac{s^3}{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)a^2b^2c^2}=\frac{s^4}{A^2\cdot a^2b^2c^2}.
\end{align*}
Thus, the $LHS$ of our identity becomes
\begin{align*}
\sum_{cyc}\frac{s}{(s-a)bc}+\frac{s^2}{A\cdot abc}
\end{align*}
I am not sure if we obtain equality ...

Answer (score 1):

we have $$AI=\frac{r}{\sin(\alpha/2)}$$ and so on, thus our statement is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha/2)^2}{r^2}+\frac{\sin(\beta/2)^2}{r^2}+\frac{\sin(\gamma/2)^2}{r^2}+\frac{\sin(\alpha/2)\sin(\beta/2)\sin(\gamma/2)}{r^3}=\frac{1}{r^2}$$
only with units we have
$$1/cm^2+1/cm^2+1/cm^2+1/cm^3=1/cm^2$$ this can not be true.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac r{AI}=\sin \frac {\alpha}2 \Rightarrow \frac 1{AI^2}=\frac{\sin^2 \frac {\alpha}2}{r^2}$$
Similarly:
$$\frac 1{BI^2}=\frac{\sin^2 \frac {\beta}2}{r^2}; \frac 1{CI^2}=\frac{\sin^2 \frac {\gamma}2}{r^2}$$
Then $$\frac {1} {AI^2}+\frac {1} {BI^2}+\frac {1} {CI^2}+\frac {1} {AI \cdot BI \cdot CI}=\frac {1} {r^2} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\frac{\sin^2 \frac {\alpha}2}{r^2}+\frac{\sin^2 \frac {\beta}2}{r^2}+\frac{\sin^2 \frac {\gamma}2}{r^2}+\frac{\sin \frac {\alpha}2 \cdot \sin \frac {\beta}2 \cdot \sin \frac {\gamma}2}{r^3}=\frac 1{r^2}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow r\left( \sin^2 \frac {\alpha}2+\sin^2 \frac {\beta}2+\sin^2 \frac {\gamma}2\right)+\sin \frac {\alpha}2 \cdot \sin \frac {\beta}2 \cdot \sin \frac {\gamma}2=r\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\sin \frac {\alpha}2 \cdot \sin \frac {\beta}2 \cdot \sin \frac {\gamma}2=r\left(1- (\sin^2 \frac {\alpha}2+\sin^2 \frac {\beta}2+\sin^2 \frac {\gamma}2)\right)$$
$$\cos \alpha+\cos \beta + \cos \gamma=4r \left(\frac {\cos \alpha+\cos \beta + \cos \gamma -1}{2} \right)$$
Let $\cos \alpha+\cos \beta + \cos \gamma=A$.

Then $$2r=\frac{A}{A-1}$$
Let $\alpha= \beta =\gamma=\frac{\pi}3$. Then $\cos \alpha+\cos \beta + \cos \gamma=\frac 32$

Then $$r=\frac 34.$$

**So for each equilateral triangle $r=\frac 34$. But this is not the case. Contradiction.**